# Are L. domus and L. domō cognates?

Tags: etymology, latin, cognates

[***domus***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domus#Etymology)

> **From Proto-Indo-European *dṓm, from root *demh₂- (“to build”)**. Cognates include Ancient Greek δόμος (dómos), Albanian dhomë (“a chamber, a room”), Sanskrit दम (dáma) and Proto-Slavic *domъ. The same Proto-Indo-European root also gave Old English timber (“building, act of building”) (English timber).

[***domō***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domo#Etymology)

> **From Proto-Indo-European *dem-h₂- (“to domesticate, tame”)**. Cognate with Sanskrit दाम्यति (dāmyati), Ancient Greek δαμνάω (damnaō), Old High German zemmen and the Proto-Germanic adjective *tamaz.

The following sentence makes me wonder and have this question: tame is a reflex of PIE *dem-h₂- (“to domesticate, tame”), which has the same formation of PIE *demh₂- (“to build”). Maybe the semantic explanation is "tamed in a house"?

***[tame](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tame&allowed_in_frame=0)***

> Old English tom, tam "domesticated, docile," from Proto-Germanic *tamaz (cf. Old Norse tamr, Old Saxon, Old Frisian, Middle Low German, Middle Dutch tam, Old High German zam, German zahm "tame," Gothic tamjan "to tame"), **from PIE *deme- "to constrain, to force, to break (horses)"** (cf. Sanskrit damayati "tames;" Persian dam "a tame animal;" Greek daman "to tame, subdue," dmetos "tame;" Latin domare "to tame, subdue;" Old Irish damnaim "I tie up, fasten, I tame, subdue"). **Possible ulterior connection with PIE *dem- "house, household" (see domestic)**. Meaning "spiritless, weak, dull" is recorded from c.1600.

Comment: It seems plausible, since there's an obvious semantic connection between "house" and "tame" (as you say): compare English *domesticate*, or Hebrew *biyet* 'tame, domesticate' from *bayt* 'house'.

Comment: The proto afro asiatic stem \*d-m "blood" may be notable as far as words for earth are related, cf. *Adam*.

Answer (score 4):

From the literature, I get the impression that this is a complicated and possibly unsolved issue. Three relevant sources I found but don't have time to analyse now:

- De Vaan, *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the Other Italic Languages* (2008):

  - On *domo*:

    > PIE *domh2-eie/o- 'to tame'.
  - On *domus*:

    > PIE *dōm, *dem- 'house'; *dom-o-?
- Ernoud & Meillet (1985) on *domo* ("domus and domo are not related):

  > Sur *domō* et *domus*, voir l'important article de  M. Benveniste, 'Homonymies  radicales en indo-européen',  *BSL* 51, 1955, p. 14 sqq. Il démontre péremptoirement que les deux mots n'ont, à l'origine, rien de commun et que *domus*, de son côté, doit être séparé de la racine *dem(ə2)- "bâtir".
- [Brouillon du texte paru in Françoise Bader (éd.), *Langues indo-européennes*, Paris, Éditions du CNRS, 1994, 43-64](http://www2.unine.ch/files/content/sites/linguistique.francaise/files/shared/documents/MethodeBader.pdf): p. 53:

  > Ainsi, Benveniste a-t-il par exemple postulé que gr. dómos "maison" résulte de la confluence tardive d'un dérivé thématisé d'un nom-racine *dom, terme institutionnel désignant une institution politique, un cercle de parenté, avec un dérivé thématique de la racine *dem-(h2)- "construire" (1955, 15-29; l'article contient des explications analogues pour d'autres racines).

Comment: Maybe someone can sift through all of this and come up with a novel insight into PIE.  There is always hope!

Comment: @MarkD, Hi, I agree with you that it is hard to totally deny the hope of the cognateness of two PIE ancesters of similar spelling and semantically possible connection.